# Vue event bus causes issue

Tags: vue.js, event-bus

I ran into a strange problem that would interesting to get some insight into. I had learned about "event bus", you create another Vue instance that you can emit events to. So I instantiated it in app.js:

```
export const bus = new Vue();
```

I hadn't even started making use of this, but I had imported it in one of my components (which is imported into the project as `Vue.component('events-view', require('./components/Events/View.vue'));`

In this component I just imported the bus:

`import { bus } from '@/app'`

That import caused a totally different page not to load its data. It had problems with date-picker (vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which stopped working. I commented out the date picker, but the initidal data wouldn't be set on the forms, no other errors showed. But in vue-devtools, I could only see the "root" element, I couldn't inspect the child component. The view is a laravel blade template that loads a vue component (imported into the project as `Vue.component('events-edit', require('./components/Events/Edit.vue')); )`.
There is no reference to the other component that loads the bus.

I found out about the problem by inspecting git diffs, and going back to when things was working, and then adding bits of code until the error appeared - and that was when I added the import of the bus (nothing else seems to cause the problem).

I am not relying on the bus so I can delete it, but I am still interested in knowing why it's happening?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or a codesandbox example?... What's the output in the developer's tools console? maybe I can help you with that information!

Comment: BTW, I strongly recommend this library for handling events: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-events) 
Works like a charm!

Comment: I do not recommend that @nachodd. `const $bus = new Vue(); Vue.prototype.$events = $bus;` does more or less the same as that package, and introduces one less risk. As for the question, it is hard to figure out exactly what happens without a [mcve]. I usually attach the bus to the prototype to have it always available without causing too much overhead, but importing it where needed should not cause a problem.

Comment: It's a good approach the one that you suggest. The thing I like about vue-events package it's the sugar sintaxis that introduces. It's so easy to manage events. But your approach it's perfectly valid :thumbsup: